# Yii2. Вывод даты рождения в field

Tags: yii2

Есть модель формы (RegistrationForm). 
Есть представление (register)

В представлении создаю форму.

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([...])
```

Хочу в качестве даты рождения вывести 3 инпут-поля. Но не создавать 3 свойства (day, month, year), а вывести одной строчкой. что-то типа

```
$form->field($model, 'birthday')
```

Что для этого необходимо сделать. Объясните, пожалуйста в двух словах.

Answer (score 0):

Единственный вариант создать в модели `RegistrationForm` свойство `birthday`. Пользователь вводит дату, после отправки POST данных, распарсить строку и отдельно внести день, месяц и год.

Comment: ситуация обратная. Необходимо собрать из 3х полей одну дату

Comment: @РадикКамалов Так а что вам мешает воспользоваться например `strtotime()` и внести туда строку из вашего дня, месяца и года, а с timestamp получить уже полноценную дату в необходимом вам формате.